# Is it feasible to use a local image in Stylus and Node.js and Express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, stylus

Here's the situation: I would like to use an image in my Web app, and in my Stylus file (`style.styl`), I can use the following code to set the image:

```
.background
    background: url(http://path/to/image)
```

However, is it feasible to save the image to my local app directory, and use it from within the directory?

My directory structure is like the follows:

```
app.js
package.json
public
    css
        style.styl
    js
    images
        image.png
views
routes
```

And I want to use the image from within the `style.styl` file, which then is parsed and used in my app when someone accesses the specific routing in my app.

However, the following code doesn't work at all:

```
.background
    background: url(../images/image.png)
```

Also the following code doesn't work

```
.background
    background: url(./public/images/image.png)
```

So, how can I use the image in my app from within the local directory?

I got [this page](http://learnboost.github.io/stylus/docs/functions.url.html) but I cannot understand everything there at all. Especially, where should I write the code on the page? It looks like it's not assumed to be written in `style.styl`, which is just a stylus file as far as I know and not a JavaScript file. Also, what should I write in the callback function?

And when I wrote the above code in my `app.js`, then I got an error: `str is not defined`, since the `stylus(str)` implies that I define a `str` object, which I don't. So I'm not sure what it does at all...

I use my Stylus file in `./public/css/` directory, and I write `app.use(require("stylus").middleware(path.join(__dirname, "public")));` in my app.js. Also, I use Express 3.5.1.

Comment: There's a missing "s" from the path. It should say "images/" not "image/image.png". Hope that didn't cost you too much time. I hate bugs like this.

Comment: Oops. Fixed. But it still doesn't work for some reasons...

Comment: Ah, OK, now working. `url(./public/images/image.png)` doesn't work while `url(../images/image.png)` worked. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah, the public folder I think is the root, so since there's no public folder within the public folder, then that makes sense. Check out your app.js for the app.use that sets up the public directory. So `url(/images/image.png)` should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might be helpful (from http://help.adobe.com/en_US/dreamweaver/cs/using/WScbb6b82af5544594822510a94ae8d65-7c44a.html - please don't use dreamweaver):

There are three types of link paths:

```
Absolute paths (such as http://www.adobe.com/support/dreamweaver/contents.html).

Document-relative paths (such as dreamweaver/contents.html).

Site root–relative paths (such as /support/dreamweaver/contents.html).
```

In express.js apps the public folder acts as the site root directory.

Comment: Thanks. Could you throw any insights on the last three paragraph of my original post, especially where I should write the code of the linked page and what it does, and what the `str` variable is...?

Comment: Stylus is pretty awesome, I'm not expert, but I've gotten used to it. I can break it down for you. Would you mind creating a new question? Just in case other people are looking to understand the same basic things about stylus, like where to put files, what stylus automatically does for you and what it doesn't, et cetera...

Comment: Thanks. I just posted the question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23159004/what-does-url-function-do-in-stylus-setup)