# What does url() function do in Stylus setup?

Tags: javascript, express, stylus

I've been following [the documentation here over official Stylus docs](http://learnboost.github.io/stylus/docs/functions.url.html) and wonder what the `url()` function does in the example code there. Especially, I would like to know where I should write the code in my projects/files... For example, if I define it in `app.js` (or `server.js`) file in my Node.js/Express application, it triggers an error: `str is not defined`, since it's obvious that I don't define `str` variable in my file.

However, I don't understand what the `str` variable is and where it does come from in the first place.

I think that the `url()` function is a wrapper that is to be executed when the actual Stylus code finds `url()` in one of its Stylus files (like `style.styl`), but beyond that, I don't get what it does nor when I define it and when I don't need to.

Anyone helps me here by clarifying it?

I use Express 3.5.1 and Stylus 0.44.

Comment: Ah, ok, now I understand your question better, I don't think I know the answer though, I'm sorry.

Answer (score 1):

It helps you turn an image into base-64 data that goes right in the stylesheet, instead of linking to the image as an external resource.

There's a very good layman's introduction to this concept [here](http://css-tricks.com/data-uris/)

It replaces the default `url()` behavior in your stylesheet if you set it up as an option.

That way, when you say:

```
.someElement
   background-image url('someImage.png')
```

instead of linking to the image file, stylus converts the image to a base-64 string and inlines it into the output style

Comment: Thanks. Then where/on which file should I write the code? Also, where does `str` variable come from?